# Reverse Geocoding with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can someone please tell me why I am getting a "geocoder is not defined" error when I run this function.  I don't understand how it couldn't have values passed from box1 and box2.  I'm looking right at the textboxes and they def have values!

```
function codeLatLng() {

var lat = document.getElementById('box1').value;
var lng = document.getElementById('box2').value;

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[1]) {
    document.getElementById('box3').value = results[1].formatted_address;  
    } 
    else {
      alert("No results found");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
  }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting an error message that says "geocoder is not defined", that tends to mean the variable/object "geocoder" is not defined.  You didn't provide any code that initializes it, but you didn't provide all your code.

Where is the "var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()" in your code?